# Testing Library: How to get parent node that has a child with Text

Tags: testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

In Testing Library, I'm trying to find a way to find elements whose children match a criteria:
Lets concider this in the container rendered in the test:

```html
    <div class="classA">
        <div class="classB">
            <div class="classC">
                some text
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="classB">
            <div class="classC">
                more text
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And I would like to find

```html
    <div class="classB">
        <div class="classC">
            some text
        </div>
    </div>
```

I tried:
`getByText(container, 'some text', {selector: 'classB'})` but it returns

```html
<div class="classC">
    some text
</div>
```

What am i missing to find the container/component/parent that would contain this text?

Comment: What's inside `container`?

Comment: Something with 2-3 level nesting like in the first code snippet. 

My goal is to be able to find a component/node that contains a text and do other assertions like: 
find info panel with name "Jason" in a child, so that I can test that another child shows favourite "colour green"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Kindly see the code below, could be helpful

```
queryAllByText((_, element) => 
element.textContent === "some text" && element.className === 'classB')
```

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know you could pass a function!
The concept is interesting but how could you refind the class matching ?
If there is extra classes 'classB themeDark'? 
I tried include rather than === but it introduced false positives like 'classB-childA
Is there a way to leverage selectors or should I split class on " "

Comment: `element.classList` would be solve your problem,`element.classList.contains('classB')`

Answer (score 5):

I know it is late, but if someone wants to get parent while querying for a text:

```
  expect(getByText('Name').parentElement?.style.left).toBe('50px');
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on the syntax? Especially: `.parentElement?.style.left`

Comment: the `.style.left` is only an example where the test being made is about the value of the style.left property (like, css), the `parentElement` should just be a property that points to the node that have the searched text inside it.

Comment: Is there a way to look for *any* parent element? Let's say I want to query for a certain text and ensure that any element up its hierarchy fits a condition, but I don't necessarily know how many levels I have to go up.